# Is it Possible to Get Line Numbers for NuGet Packages in a Stack Trace?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, stack-trace

I'm wondering if it's possible to via a setting or option of some kind to get line numbers to appear in a stack trace for code in a NuGet package that's being used by a .Net app. The example screenshot below may make my question clearer.

[image]

The green boxed section is the .Net app and the red boxed section is code in a NuGet package being consumed and called by the app. I'm wondering if there's a way to get a line number to show up where the red arrow is? Some of our packages are hundreds of lines long and having the ability to see the line number where the error occurred in the NuGet package code would be very helpful.

Comment: In some cases, NuGet packages may ship their symbols as part of the package, either as PDB files or using embedded symbols in the DLL. Such packages _should_ allow their source information to be included in stack traces. It's pretty much in the control of the author though, I don't believe you can influence it as a consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you're using Private Symbols:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/public-and-private-symbols